# How to refactor try..catch() which is used in Laravel functions of the same Controller

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, laravel-8

I have Controller like this:

```
class TronController extends Controller
{
    public $tron;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->fullNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
        $this->solidityNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
        $this->eventServer = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
    }

    public function totalUsers()
    {
        try {
            $tron = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Tron($this->fullNode, $this->solidityNode, $this->eventServer);
            $TransactionBuilder = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\TransactionBuilder($tron);

        } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
        $address = ADDRESS;
        $addressH = $tron->toHex($address);
        $contract = CONTRACT;
        $contractH = $tron->toHex($contract);
        ...
    }

    public function totalTickets()
    {
        try {
            $tron = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Tron($this->fullNode, $this->solidityNode, $this->eventServer);
            $TransactionBuilder = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\TransactionBuilder($tron);

        } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

So as you can see, at the two functions of this Controller, I have repeated the same `try..catch()` for setting up `$trone` variable.

Now in order to refactor this,  I added `try..catch()` to the `__construct()` function:

```
       public function __construct(){
            $this->fullNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
            $this->solidityNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
            $this->eventServer = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');

            try {
               $tron = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Tron($this->fullNode, $this->solidityNode, $this->eventServer);
               $TransactionBuilder = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\TransactionBuilder($tron);

           } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
               exit($e->getMessage());
           }
        }
```

But this will return an **ErrorException**:

`Undefined variable: tron`

Which is referring to this line:

`$addressH = $tron->toHex($address);`

So the question is, how can I write less code by minimizing the `try..catch()` and use that in the functions without getting error ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where did use this variable. Screen this line

Comment: Please double-check this is the actual code you're running, and remove caches if necessary. I can't imagine that error message coming from this code.

Comment: It looks fine to me just created a [**sample demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ef0031517fbb41434a9155eb57bbe9054c30bd6) similar to your sample code and its working, Can you please check if there is any caching involved

Comment: don't perform network/disk I/O in controller constructor. They can be run before a request is passed to the controller, or in command line when you run `route:list`. Move the duplicate code into a new function and call it from totalUsers() and totalTickets() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're setting an instance variable but you're not really using it: `public $tron;`

Then you simply create a new local variable instead:
`$tron = new ...`

I suggest making use of the class variable by using `$this->tron`

In your case I would place it in the constructor, much like Stephen said, like so:
(I also made some changes to your class declaration)

```
class TronController extends Controller
{
    public $tron; // Consider whether you really need this public or not
    protected $fullNode; // Adding these definitions as protected so you can change/use them in child classes
    protected $solidityNode;
    protected $eventServer;
    protected $transactionBuilder; // This may need to be public, I'm not familiar with tron. I saw you weren't using this so maybe you didn't want it to be local, so here you go, now it's a class member

    public function __construct(){
        $this->fullNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
        $this->solidityNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
        $this->eventServer = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');

        try {
            $this->tron = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Tron($this->fullNode, $this->solidityNode, $this->eventServer);
            $this->transactionBuilder = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\TransactionBuilder($this->tron);
        } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function totalUsers()
    {
        $tron = $this->tron; // Avoiding the repetition of '$this'
        $address = ADDRESS;
        $addressH = $tron->toHex($address);
        $contract = CONTRACT;
        $contractH = $tron->toHex($contract);
        //
    }

    public function totalTickets()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

P.S.: It seems to me like you may need to read a bit more about OOP in PHP, particularly about visibility. [Check the documentation out :)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: It will be much better and cleaner, if this `HttpProvider` depedency is injected to `TronController` via `ServiceProvider`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$addressH = $tron->toHex($address);` references a *local* variable `$tron` within the `totalUsers` and `totalTickets` methods.

Try this instead:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider;
use IEXBase\TronAPI\TransactionBuilder;
use IEXBase\TronAPI\Tron;
use IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException;

class TronController extends Controller
{
    public Tron $tron;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Not sure why you're doing the same thing three times
        $fullNode = new HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
        $solidityNode = new HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
        $eventServer = new HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');

        try {
            $this->tron = new Tron($fullNode, $solidityNode, $eventServer);

            // You don't appear to be using this anywhere...
            $transactionBuilder = new TransactionBuilder($this->tron);
        } catch (TronException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function totalUsers()
    {
        // Reference the class instance variable $tron
        $addressH = $this->tron->toHex('Some address');
    }


    public function totalTickets()
    {
        // Reference the class instance variable $tron
        $addressH = $this->tron->toHex('Some address');
    }
}
```